# Figure numbering parameters

Tags: floats, numbering

I define new parameters for chapter numbering, named MyChapter. I use the command

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\theMyChapter.\arabic{figure}}
```

for figure numbering. But after the figures are numbered, it adds the symbol ":" at the end of it, such as: "figure 1.2: ". I want to remove this symbol or exchange it with the symbol dot. What should I do?

Comment: do you use `caption` packages? by it you can achieve your wish with `labelsep=period`

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ and which packages (such as `caption` and `subfig`) you may load that are designed to modify the appearance of captions. If you do load a package such as `caption` or `subfig`, please tell us more about any package-related instructions may be in your code.

Comment: @Mico: I am using book document class. The caption seems to be a good package which is suggested by Zakro.  More suggestion would be interested for me, if any.